# Mocking URLSession to return a Mocked URLSessionDataTask

Tags: swift, mocking

I want to mock `URLSession`, and return a mocked `URLSessionDataTask`.

To Mock `URLSession` I create a protocol

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
}
```

that `URLSession` can then conform to in an extension

```
extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {}
```

Now I want to do the same for `URLSessionDataTask`, and so implement a similar protocol and extension for it. I need to do this, since the way I call `URLSession` requires use of `func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask`

```
protocol URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    func resume()
}

extension URLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {}
```

So then my `URLSessionDataTask` mock is set up as follows:

```
class URLSessionMock: URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias CompletionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
    // data and error can be set to provide data or an error
    var data: Data?
    var error: Error?
    func dataTask(
        with url: URL,
        completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler
        ) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        let data = self.data
        let error = self.error
        return URLSessionDataTaskMock {
            completionHandler(data, nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

With my `URLSessionDataTaskMock` presented with:

```
class URLSessionDataTaskMock: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    private let closure: () -> Void
    init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
    // override resume and call the closure

    func resume() {
        closure()
    }
}
```

Doesn't work since `URLSessionDataTaskMock` within the `URLSessionProtocol` isn't the correct return type - I need to return a `URLSessionDataTask`.

I can't cast my `URLSessionDataTaskMock` to `URLSessionDataTask` as the types are not related.

How can I return my `URLSessionDataTaskMock` from my `URLSessionProtocol`?

Comment: Typically what you want to do is define a protocol then define two more classes conforming to your protocol. The first class would wrap URLSession and your mock would be implemented however you want.

Comment: URLSessionMock and URLSession conform to URLSessionProtocol (So two classes conform to the protocol). However the function dataTask returns a URLSessionDataTask that I want to mock. I don't want to change production code to test, I want to use a standard URLSession and then Mock it. So how do I adequately return  URLSessionDataTaskMock as URLSessionDataTask within URLSessionMock.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I it's getting late and I misread your post. This is a tough problem to solve. Let me think about this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, I probably didn't make things clear (and I've had this problem for a long time, and want a good solution really....it just keeps cropping up in different forms...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably get away with something like this. The key would be your associated type in your URLSessionProtocol

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    associatedtype DataTaskType
    func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> DataTaskType
}

extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {}

protocol URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    func resume()
}

extension URLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {}

class URLSessionDataTaskMock: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    typealias CompletionHandler = URLSessionMock.CompletionHandler

    private let completion: CompletionHandler

    init(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        self.completion = completion
    }

    func resume() {
        // create some data
        completion(nil, nil, nil)
    }
}

class URLSessionMock: URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias CompletionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
    // data and error can be set to provide data or an error
    var data: Data?
    var error: Error?
    func dataTask(
        with url: URL,
        completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler
    ) -> URLSessionDataTaskMock {
        return URLSessionDataTaskMock(completion: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to be able to use the returned dataTask properly you need to do a small tweak: `associatedtype DataTaskType: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol`